Unable to mount fileshare as a network drive, even after connecting with P2S VPN
I have a fileshare-only storage account that has been disabled from public networks, and only selected VNET and their subnets can mount the fileshare on their system. I already knew fileshare works on SMB protocol and cannot be accessed directly so we have to use a P2S VPN in order to mount the fileshare as a network drive.

I have successfully configured the P2S VPN on my local system and validated the same.
Problem: Even after connecting with the P2S VPN, I still have to whitelist my public IP in the firewall section every time, as I have a dynamic IP address. Whitelisting every time is not helping me solve the problem.
Hence whitelisting the public IP address does solve the problem temporarily.
How to permanently solve this permanently?
I tried whitelisting the entire CIDR range of the gateway but that did not help.
Since I have a dynamic public IP address, whitelisting everytime is not feasible.
There are options mainly what I have read is forced tunnelling, Filesync and Storage Explorer but that isn't what I am expecting to use.
And since the below connect pane itself displays that after connecting with the P2S VPN we would be able to mount the fileshare, but I have to additionally whitelist my IP.


Create a private endpoint for the storage account, add a local hostentry on your local machine with the PE IP and fileshare endpoint, and then try to mount the fileshare through p2s VPN.


Unable to mount file share as a network drive, even after connecting with P2S VPN.

If you are unable to mount the Azure file share via P2S VPN, check the following steps.

First, check if the storage account is configured with a private endpoint. If not, create a private endpoint and associate it with the storage account.


Note: If a private endpoint for the storage account is not created, you may need to hardcode the IP address for the public endpoint of the Azure storage. However, since the Azure Storage cluster IP changes frequently, hardcoding the IP address can be very difficult. Follow the MS Doc for more details


Private Endpoint Configuration

When I connected to the VPN and added the local host entry on my machine, the file share was mounted successfully.
Private DNS Configuration

Local Hostentry
10.0.0.4    demostoragetestdemo.file.core.windows.net

VPN Connectivity

Output:


Thank You for your approach.
As you rightly mentioned about the private endpoint, I have already tried that which works.VWAN is configured instead of a VPN gateway.
The issue is that I can only mount the file share as a network drive after connecting to my P2S VPN and only if I whitelist my IP, and my IP is dynamic.
Even if I have connected myself to the VPN, pinging the file share URL gives "Destination Host Unreachable", and once I whitelist the IP the pingback states "Request Time Out", and only then I can access the network drive.

Ping is not the correct way to test connectivity, but this was what I observed.

The private endpoint is set up for the DNS at storage account. It is necessary to add the hostentry on the local device when connecting to the VPN.It is very difficult to add hostentry without PE.no matter how your configured your VPN configuration.

If you have whitelisted public IP addresses in the storage firewall section, there is no point in connecting a VPN. Traffic from IP addresses to storage will be accepted.

I hope this helps to resolve your issue.
